# oracleConnection.close() dont close the connection in my session browser

Tags: c#, oracle

I make run of test connection, I expect to see clear session browser,
but at the end of the program, I see more then 6 sessions in my session browser

This is the code:

```
private void testConnection()        
{   
        string connectionString = "data source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=1111)(PORT=1699))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = abcd)));Min Pool Size=10; Connection Lifetime=120;";

        OracleConnection oraConn = new OracleConnection(connectionString);

        try
        {
            oraConn.Open();
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }

        finally
        {
            oraConn.Dispose();
            oraConn.Close();
        }

    }
```

I need a solution to close session totaly.

Comment: Are there any exceptions on connection close?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should clear the pool:

```
 finally
    {
        oraConn.Dispose();
        oraConn.Close();
        OracleConnection.ClearPool(oraConn);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason is likely connection pooling. From MSDN:

[OracleConnection.Close Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnection.close.aspx)

> The Close method rolls back any pending transactions. It then releases
>   the connection to the connection pool, or closes the connection if
>   connection pooling is disabled.

So, your connection instance will get disposed of within C# but the connection may stay open in the pool, so that a new open connection instance may be quickly provided the next time you request one.

Comment: And why do I see 6 rows in the session browser?

Comment: Because the connection pool is a pool of many connections, not a single one. It keeps several open so that it can rapidly provide them.

Comment: Thanks about your clearly answer! but our DBA complainant about my open connections, because it causes DataBase to be slow....     Have you a solution??????

Comment: If you wish, you may disable connection pooling, but I think you will find it has no bearing on overall database performance.

Comment: @user1012506 That would best be asked as a new question.